# Does a $\sigma$-finite measure always admit a countable partition whose components are uniformly bounded from below and/or above?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(A,\mathcal{A})$ be a measure space and $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite
  measure on $A$ such that $\mu(A)=\infty$. 
Is it true that then one can find a
  partition $(A_m)_{m \geq 1}$ of $A$ such that not only $\mu(A_m) <\infty$, but
  also $\mu(A_m) > \delta$ for all $m$, where $\delta$ is some arbitrary
  positive number? What about an upper bound, i.e. can we always find a partition such that $\mu(A_m) < M$ for all $m$ and some arbitrary positive number $M$?

I know that this is a rather elementary question but would still be thankful for a quick assurance that my proof below for the lower bound is correct and some comments for the upper bound.

Comment: I've thought about it and the upper bound part of the questions is false in general. One can for example define a measure $\mu$ on the positive integers (with the power set as $\sigma$-algebra) by setting $\mu(n)=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof for the lower bound: First, let $(B_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a partition of $A$ such that $\mu(B_n) <
  \infty$ for all $n \geq 1$. Then, for $m \geq 0$, inductively define positive
  integers $k_m$ by setting $k_0=0$ 
  and, for $m \geq 1$,
  $$ k_{m+1} = \operatorname{min} \left\{ k > k_m \, \colon \, \mu \left(
      \bigcup_{n=k_{m}+1}^{k} B_{n} \right) > \delta \right\},$$
  where we set $\min \emptyset = \infty$. 
  Assume that the set $\{m \colon k_m = \infty\}$ is not empty and choose its smallest element $m_0$. Then $\mu \left( \bigcup_{n=k_{m_0-1}+1}^{\infty}
    B_n \right) < \delta$ and thus $\mu(A) = \mu \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{k_{m_0-1}} B_n
  \right) + \mu \left( \bigcup_{n=k_{m_0-1}+1}^{\infty} B_n \right) < \infty$, which
  is a contradiction. Thus $k_m < \infty$ for all $m \geq 0$ and the
  partition $(A_m)_{m \geq 1}$ defined by
  $$A_m = \bigcup_{n=k_{m-1}+1}^{k_m} B_n$$
  has the required property.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ a set of all natural numbers and $\cal{A}$ be powerset of $A$. Let $\lambda(\{n\})=n$ for each $n \in N$. We define a measure $\mu$ on $\cal{A}$ as follows: $\mu(X)=\sum_{n \in  X}\lambda(\{n\})$. Then $\mu$ is a σ-finite measure on A such that $\mu(A)=+\infty$, there is a partition $(A_m)_{m≥1}$ of $A$ such that not only $\mu(A_m)<\infty$ , but also $\mu(A_m)>\delta$ for all $m$, where $\delta$ is some arbitrary positive number and there is no an upper bound, i.e.  for an arbitrary partition $(B_m)_{m \in N}$ there does not exist a positive number $M$ such that $\mu(B_m)<M$ for all $m$.

Comment: This reproduces an earlier comment by another user without saying so and leaves the (more interesting) question of the lower bound unsolved.

Comment: @Gogi I've already given a general proof (not just an example) for the fact that you can always find a partition with a lower bound. Moreover, in my comment to the original question above, I've given the exact same example that you restated here (with slightly different notation) that there isn't always an upper bound. Didn't you see this?

Comment: @herrsimon,  You are right.